# Twilio Bulk Messages with ShortCode throughput with C#

Tags: c#, twilio

I am trying to track down a performance issue that is not allowing me to send more than 3 or so message with the twilio c# api.  In short, we have a windows service that responds to bulk 'JOIN' messages.  See the following code:

```
        int i = 0;
        DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);
        foreach (CustomerTextMessage t in o)
        {
            i++;
            ThreadInput ti = new ThreadInput { MessageIds = i, Body = t.Body, ThreadCreated = DateTime.Now, FromNumber = t.FromNumber };
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ProcessResponseList), (object)ti);
        }
```

The ProcessResponseList method does a quick look up on the customer, then responds using this method:

```
    public static void SendResponse(string number, string body)
    {
        string AccountSid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AccountSid"];
        string AuthToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AccountToken"];
        var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);


        string fromNumber = "";

        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StageExecution"] == "true")
        {
            BusinessLayer.SLOSBL.Logger logger = new BusinessLayer.SLOSBL.Logger("DiscoverTextMessagingService", "DiscoverTextMessagingService");
            AuthToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StageApplicationToken"];
            var longCodes = twilio.ListIncomingPhoneNumbers(null, "StagePhoneNumber", null, null);
            fromNumber = longCodes.IncomingPhoneNumbers[1].PhoneNumber;
            logger.Notify("Sending text message to:  " + number + " from Twilio number:  " + fromNumber + ".  The body of the message reads:  " + body);
        }
        else
        {
            var shortCodes = twilio.ListShortCodes(null, null);
            fromNumber = "+" + shortCodes.ShortCodes[0].ShortCode;
        }

        //var message = twilio.SendMessage(fromNumber, number, body, new string[0], null, AuthToken );
        DateTime d = DateTime.Now;

        twilio.SendMessage(fromNumber, number, body, new string[0], null, AuthToken, null, m => { MessageAsyncCallBack(m, d); });

    }
```

What I am seeing is that it is able to send these message about 3 every second.  I am really looking to increase that closer to the 30 every second that a short code is possible but I am not able to even get them to the twilio queue fast enough.  So my question, is there anything obvious that I should be doing?  Should I be reusing the TwilioRestClient variable for all message?  Is there a limit to the number of connections someplace that I am missing?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You absolutely should only create the TwilioRestClient one time. It is reusable and it does use a bit of overhead. That would be the first thing I would try to solve and see if it fixes your performance issues.